# Reapeat/replay a session x times with a different request header

Tags: fiddler, jscript, fiddlercore, fiddler-dev

is it possible to reapeat/replay a session x times with a different reaquest header.

I was thinking of a for loop inside `OnBeforeRequest` which will iterate over the same request from the session, but with a different parameter for the request header ...

But I am kind of lost, can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for (var i=0; i< 50; i++)
    {      
        var oSD = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary();
        oSD.Add("x-Builder-MaxRedir", "10");
        var oRH: Fiddler.HTTPRequestHeaders = new Fiddler.HTTPRequestHeaders();

        var oURI: System.Uri = new Uri("https://whatever.com/" + i.ToString());

        var sHeaders: String = String.Format("GET {0} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {1}\r\n\r\n", oURI.PathAndQuery, oURI.Host);
  // ^^^ Add any header you like here, then...
        oRH.AssignFromString(sHeaders);          
        var newSession = FiddlerApplication.oProxy.SendRequest(oRH, null, oSD);

    }
```